# Problems opening ArcGIS 10.3.1 .shp files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, arcgis-10.3, import

I'm using QGIS version 2.12.1-Lyon for Mac and trying to import a .shp file that was apparently created with ArcGIS 10.3.1. I keep receiving the "invalid data source" error message no matter how I try to import the file (drag and drop, import layers drop down menu, QGIS file browser). Is it possible that .shp files created with ArcGIS 10.3.1 are not compatible with QGIS? Is there some sort of tip or trick that can be used to get around this so that I can import the file?

Comment: Some ideas... check that the usual files that comprise the file (.shx, .dbf, .prj, .sbn) are in the same folder as the .shp. Also make sure that the folder the .shp is in is not zipped... I often myself trying to add a zipped .shp because Explorer lets you 'look into' a zipped file now. Sometimes shapefiles can actually break as well.

Comment: A shapefile is composed by at leat 3 files; SHP, SHX and DBF. Make sure you have them. @alex QGIS can read shapefile inside zip files.

Comment: You can drag & drop zipped folders in QGIS but if you open the zipped folder in Explorer on Windows you can't drag and drop the .shp file without unzipping it first.